# winddk.h and WDK 10 problems in vs2015

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, wdk, emokit

I have a C project(*emotiv-emokit-c*:https://github.com/petrs/emokit/) that I'm trying to understand, working on Windows 10, VS2015 that additionally required *winddk.h* along with:

*hidpi.h,*

*hidsdi.h,*

*hidusage.h,*

*setupapi.h,*

*hid.lib*

which I downloaded from the internet, unknowing that they're all part of WDK. Upon compilation **only** winddk.h gave +100 errors, they were mostly:

**variable NTSOAPI is not a type name**

**variable NTSTATUS is not a type name**

**variable PVOID is not a type name**

**variable ULONG is not a type name**

**plenty of expected ';''s**

**_ULARGE_INTEGER:'union' type redefinition**

**_SINGLE_LIST_ENTRY:'union' type redefinition**

**_PROCESSOR_NUMBER:'union' type redefinition**

**etc.**

I had a WDK 7.6 image on my drive, which I installed, then noticing it might not be what visual studio 2015 requires, I installed WDK windows 10, but now I don't know how to implement this new headers(*whichever winddk.h requires along its side*) contained in WDK. When compiled it gives the same errors as before wth few new one, like:

**redeclaration cannot add dllexport/dllimport to "InterlockedPopEntrySList" (declared at line 58 of "c:\Program Files (86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\interlockedapi.h")**

which means that the last WDK 10 I've installed is not being affective or it also requires Windows SDK which I remember updating 8.1 SDK few weeks ago.

I'm not sure what to do to next. Even if i remove the downloaded winddk.h and others from the project directory, I don't know how to apply this wdk/sdk to fix this headers issue, before moving any further.

I would appreciate, if someone could help me.

Answer (score -1):

Look up where "winddk.h" is located on your installation and put the directory in the extra include path in the projects includes.